# Find the following limit: $\lim\limits_{x \to 1} \left(\frac{f(x)}{f(1)}\right)^{1/\log(x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> find the following limit
>
> $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=1$ and $f(1)>0$
>
> $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{f(1)}\right)^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}$

why can i just substitute $x$ for $1$ and thats will be the limit (since $f$ is differentiable, it is also continuous...)

Comment: If you substitute $x = 1$, your exponent is poorly behaved....

Comment: ooh..., so what do i need to do?

Comment: Hint: $\log f$ is also differentiable at $1$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limits and derivatives - two questions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618169/limits-and-derivatives-two-questions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \left(\dfrac{f(x)}{f(1)}\right)^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}= e^{\lim_{x \to 1}(\frac{f(x)}{f(1)}-1)\frac{1}{\ln x}} = e^{\frac{1}{f(1)}\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}\frac{x-1}{\ln x}}=e^{\frac{1}{f(1)}\cdot f'(1)\cdot1}=e^{\frac{f'(1)}{f(1)}}$$

Comment: why is the first step allowed? if you want to use $e$ shouldn't the power be surrounded with $\ln$?

Comment: @guynaa $a^b=e^{b \ln a}$

Comment: but you dident put $\left(\dfrac{f(x)}{f(1)}\right)$ inside $\ln$...

Answer (score 5):

We have by the definition of the derivative:
$$\lim_{x \to 1} \left(\dfrac{f(x)}{f(1)}\right)^{\frac{1}{\log(x)}}=\lim_{x \to 1}\exp\left(\frac{\log f(x)-\log f(1)}{x-1}\frac{x-1}{\log(x)}\right)\\=\exp\left(\frac{(\log f(x))'\big|_{x=1}}{(\log x)'\big|_{x=1}}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{f'(1)}{f(1)}\right)$$

Comment: could you please explain what you did in each step?

Comment: In the first step I just rewrite the expression using $\exp\log$ functions and to appear the form 
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$
and the second step is to pass to the limit $$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(a)$$

Comment: @guynaa. If $\lim^|_{x→α}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x→α}g(x)=∞$ then there is "the shortcut"$\lim_{x→α}(f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{\lim_{x→α}(f(x)−1)g(x)}$

Comment: can you point me to a reference to this "shortcut"?

Comment: It is a  consequence of remarkable limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n=e$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

1. \begin{align}\color{#0000ff}{\large%
   \lim_{x \to 1}\bracks{\fermi\pars{x} \over \fermi\pars{1}}^{1/\ln\pars{x}}}
   &=
   \lim_{x \to \infty}
   \bracks{\fermi\pars{1 + 1/x} \over \fermi\pars{1}}^{1/\ln\pars{1 + 1/x}}
   =
   \lim_{x \to \infty}
   \bracks{1 + {\fermi'\pars{1} \over \fermi\pars{1}}\,{1 \over x}}^{x}
   \\[3mm]&=
   \lim_{x \to \infty}
   \exp\pars{x\ln\pars{1 + {\fermi'\pars{1} \over \fermi\pars{1}}\,{1 \over x}}}
   =
   \lim_{x \to \infty}
   \exp\pars{x\bracks{{\fermi'\pars{1} \over \fermi\pars{1}}\,{1 \over x}}}
   \\[3mm]&= \color{#0000ff}{\large\expo{\fermi'\pars{1}/\fermi\pars{1}}}
   \end{align}
2. \begin{align}
   \lim_{x \to 1}\ln\pars{\bracks{\fermi\pars{x} \over \fermi\pars{1}}^{1/\ln\pars{x}}}
   &=
   \lim_{x \to 1}{\ln\pars{\fermi\pars{x}/\fermi\pars{1}} \over \ln\pars{x}}
   =
   \lim_{x \to 1}{\fermi'\pars{x}/\fermi\pars{x} \over 1/x}
   =
   {\fermi'\pars{1} \over \fermi\pars{1}}
   \\[3mm]&\quad\imp\quad
   \color{#0000ff}{\large%
   \lim_{x \to 1}\bracks{\fermi\pars{x} \over \fermi\pars{1}}^{1/\ln\pars{x}}}
   =
   \color{#0000ff}{\large\expo{\fermi'\pars{1}/\fermi\pars{1}}}
   \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Let $L$ be the limit you want to find. Then using L'Hospital's rule,

\begin{align*}
\ln L &= \lim_{x \to 1} \ln \left(\frac{f(x)}{f(1)}\right)^{1/\ln{x}} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\ln f(x) - \ln f(1)}{\ln x} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 1} \dfrac{\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}}{\dfrac 1 x} \\
&= \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x f'(x)}{f(x)}
\end{align*}

Can you fill in the details, and find the limit from here?

Comment: i cant use L'Hospital's rule, we haven't covered it yet