# finding a limit of a general function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, functions

${\rm f}$ is differentiable at ${\rm f}\left(1\right),\,$
${\rm f}\left(1\right) > 0$.

Calculate the following limit, and here's what I did:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty }\left[%
{\rm f}\left(1 + 1/n\right) \over {\rm f}\left(1\right)\right]^{1/n}
=
\left[{\rm f}\left(1\right) \over {\rm f}\left(1\right)\right]^{0} = 1
$$

Now, On the one hand, I can't see why the above isn't true. On the other hand, I got this hunch something is wrong here.

Can you direct me please?

Comment: Look this one ---> http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/621715/find-the-following-limit-lim-limits-x-to-1-left-dfracfxf1-right/621724#621724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to write $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{f(1 + \frac{1}{n})}{f(1)} \right)^{\!n},$$ not $1/n$, since the expression as written is trivially always $1$ given that $0 < f(1) < \infty$.

Consider the logarithm:  $$ \log \left( \frac{f(1 + \frac{1}{n})}{f(1)} \right)^{\!n} = \frac{\log f(1 + \frac{1}{n}) - \log f(1)}{1/n}. $$  Then by the definition of derivative $$ g'(a) = \lim_{t \to a} \frac{g(t) - g(a)}{t-a}$$ with the choice $a = 1$, $g = \log f$, and $t = 1 + 1/n$, we see that the limit of the logarithm is simply the derivative of $\log f$ at $x = 1$; i.e., $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{f(1 + \frac{1}{n})}{f(1)} \right)^n = \exp \left( \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \log f(x) \right]_{x=1} \right) = \exp \frac{f'(1)}{f(1)},$$ which is the more interesting case.

Comment: No, I actually meant $1 \over n$

Comment: In that case, the answer is trivially 1, as I stated at the beginning of my response.  This is because the expression $1^0$ is not an indeterminate form:  $f(1) > 0$ is constant and $f(1 + 1/n) \to f(1)$ as $n \to \infty$ because you stipulated that $f$ is differentiable at $1$.  There is no hidden subtlety or trick.

Comment: Lets assume we didn't know whether or not $f(1)$ is differentiable, How would it make a difference?

Comment: If we do not assume the existence of a derivative to $f$ at $1$, then the limit runs into an obvious flaw if the function exhibits a discontinuity at this point (recall differentiability implies continuity, and it is the latter criterion that is required for the limit to exist in this case):  for example, consider $f(1) = 1$, but $f(x) = 1/(x-1)$ if $x \ne 1$.  You can immediately see how this runs into a problem.

Comment: You've been very helpful. Thanks, things much more clear to me know

Answer (score 2):

What you did is something like the following.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n=\left(1+0\right)^{\infty}=1.$$
As you know the correct answer is $e$.

The reason why you cannot do like this is that the exponent $n$ does influence $1+1/n$.

Your case is the same as above. The exponent $1/n$ does influence the inside. So you cannot use limit to separate $n$s.

Don't confuse this with the following :
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)=(1+0)\cdot (1+0)=1.$$
This is correct.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
When $n \gg 1$:
$$
\bracks{\fermi\pars{1 + 1/n} \over \fermi\pars{1}}^{1/n}
\sim
\bracks{1 + {\fermi'\pars{1} \over \fermi\pars{1}n}}^{1/n}
=
\exp\pars{{1 \over n}\,\ln\pars{1 + {\fermi'\pars{1} \over \fermi\pars{1}n}}}
\sim
\exp\pars{{1 \over n}\,\bracks{{\fermi'\pars{1} \over \fermi\pars{1}n}}}
$$
So,
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\fermi\pars{1 + 1/n} \over \fermi\pars{1}}^{1/n}
=1}
$$

Comment: No, this is not correct, as I explained in my response.  Indeed, your own computation is not consistent, since you have a factor of $n^2$ in the denominator that does not cancel out.

Comment: @heropup Any $\displaystyle{\large{1 \over n^{2}}}$ cancels in the limit $\displaystyle{\large n \to \infty}$ due to the product $\displaystyle{\large n\,{1 \over n^{2}}}$.

Comment: @heropup I already solved in two different ways:  http://math.stackexchange.com/a/621724/85343

Comment: Read your original post more carefully:  You wrote $$\left(\frac{f(1+1/n)}{f(1)}\right)^{\!1/n} \sim \exp\left( \frac{1}{n} \frac{f'(1)}{f(1)n} \right).$$ But since $f'(1)/f(1)$ is finite and constant with respect to $n$, then as $n \to \infty$, $\exp\left( \frac{1}{n} \frac{f'(1)}{f(1)n} \right) \to \exp(0) = 1$, not $\exp(f'(1)/f(1))$ as you claimed in the blue text.

Comment: @heropup You are right. I was really blind !!!. Thanks.